# How do I lock a HTML table column in place so it doesn't move dynamically?

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table, locking

I just created a two column, one row table on a Wordpress page. You can see it here: http://www.masteringbodyweightexercise.com/feats-of-strength/

The image I placed in the first column keeps getting smaller as I type into the second column.

How can I lock the first column, or the image in it, so it doesn't get smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use CSS:

```
table-layout:fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

play arround with fixed, like :

```
<table class="fixed">
    <col width="20px" />
    <col width="30px" />
    <col width="40px" />
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```